# How to call a def in a class within kivy screen change

Tags: python, function, class, kivy

I'm trying to change from one screen to another. But the problem is I cannot call the def inside the class I want to change the screen too.

```
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
        def remove_code(self):
            main = Main_app()
            self.parent.current = main.main_run()

    class Main_app(Screen):
        def main_run(self):
            self.add_widget(Label(text="Test 1", color=(1,0,0,1), font_size=(30),size_hint=(0.4,0.15), pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top": 0.93}))
```

It just changes the screen to Main_App screen and doesn't show the label. So its like it ingores the `.main_run()` How can I make it so it changes and shows the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
self.parent.current = main
```

You're most likely just changing which screen is current.

You should be able to do what you need one of two ways.

```
self.parent.get_screen('INSERTSCREENNAMEHERE').main_run()
```

Where screen name, is the name you gave the screen when you added it to the manager, you can also do:

```
self.parent.screens[SCREENINDEXHERE].main_run()
```

Where screen index is the number at which point the screen was added to the list (ie, if screentwo was added as the second screen, you'd get the second index (ie one).

Also, you can use manager instead of parent for screens as well.

Comment: I changed the question abit. I want it to show the label inside the def when it switches screens to Main_app.main_run. (mian_run is the def.)

Comment: I misunderstood your question. To do this, you can use the on_enter method:

All you need to do is to change 'def main_run' under your Main_app screen to 'def on_enter' which means it will trigger that code anytime you enter that screen. You don't need the 'remove_code' method as well.

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

Comment: Oooh, I see now. I get it. So "on_enter" does it show when the screen is called and changed to it calls that function. Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah. You can also use 'on_leave' to remove the widget if you need to (otherwise you'd end up creating a widget per entry which might become too much).